# post event pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Can somebody help and show me how `pygame.event.post()` function work? My code looks like this:

```python
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # importing pygame and creating display     
    def main(self):
        class fire_events(object):
            def __iter__(self):
                return self
            def next(self):
                return pygame.event.wait()
        # Main loop
            for event in fire_events():
                print "a"
                # DO SOME STUFF
    def post_my_event(self)
        #pygame.event.post doesnt work - it complains pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

So basically I just want to create my application, let it run in the main loop and then post a event from outside code and have pygame react to it.

Comment: have you tried calling pygame init() functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just magically put an `Event` from *outside* your application into pygames event queue.

If you want to do something like this, you have to use some kind of IPC or networking.

An easy way would be using UDP for example.

This class will respond to UDP messages and put the event into `pygame`'s event queue:

```
import socket
import pygame

pygame.init()

class UdpToPygame():

    def __init__(self):
        UDP_IP="127.0.0.1"
        UDP_PORT=15006
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.setblocking(0)
        self.sock.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))

    def update(self):
        try:
            data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
            ev = pygame.event.Event(pygame.USEREVENT, {'data': data, 'addr': addr})
            pygame.event.post(ev)
        except socket.error:
            pass
```

In your `pygame` application, you would create an instance of that class and call the `update` method in your main loop.

A sample application that responds to the custom events `UdpToPygame` will put into the queue:

```
def main():
    dispatcher = UdpToPygame()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    l = 0
    r = True
    while r:
        for ev in pygame.event.get():
            if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
                r = False
            if ev.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
                t = pygame.font.SysFont('', 40).render(ev.data, True, (255,255,255))
                screen.blit(t, (0, l*20))
                l += 1
        dispatcher.update()        
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Run this and fire up a python interpreter to send text directly to your running pygame application:

```
>>> import socket
>>> sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> while True:
...     sock.sendto(raw_input(), ("127.0.0.1", 15006))
...
hallo
5
pygame....
10
```

**EDIT:**

As for your error `pygame.error: video system not initialized`:

Ensure you initialized pygame with `pygame.init()`.

Comment: thanks, thats exactly what I needed. You made it crystal clear to me :)

Comment: I called the init() function in where it says # importing pygame and creating display, so that is not the issue