# My threading is not exactly working like i want it to

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

Ok So I am doing a school project for which I am Using threads to go from a phone Home Screen to a chat app and i have used threads in both application.

```
import pygame as pyg, sys, cv2, random, os, handDetector, time, threading
import pywhatkit, pyjokes, pyttsx3 as pyt
import speech_recognition as sr, chatApp, server1

class homeScreen:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width, self.height = 400, 600
        self.window = pyg.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        self.webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.hand = handDetector.handDetector(maxhands=1)
        self.run = True
        self.image = pyg.image.load(f"/Users/surya/Desktop/SuryaFolder/SuryaAssets/nature/Image_10.jpg")
        self.googleWidget = pyg.image.load("SuryaAssets/googleWidget.png")
        self.googleWidget = pyg.transform.smoothscale(self.googleWidget, (self.width-50, self.height*(self.width/self.googleWidget.get_width())))
        self.image = pyg.transform.smoothscale(self.image, (self.width, self.height))
        self.chatsappIcon = pyg.image.load("SuryaAssets/download-16.jpg")
        self.chatsappIcon = pyg.transform.smoothscale(self.chatsappIcon, (40, 40))
        self.pTime = 0
        self.microphoneRect = pyg.Rect(320, 52, 25, 20)
        self.x = y = 0
        self.select = False
        self.googleAssistant = False
        self.c = ''
        self.a1 = False
        self.run1 = False
        self.engine = pyt.Engine()
        self.a = False
        self.listener = sr.Recognizer()
        self.run1 = False
        self.command = ''
        self.newserver = False
        self.d = threading.Thread(target=self.mainScreen,).start()
        self.b = threading.Thread(target=self.function,).start()
        self.g =  threading.Thread(target=(server1.function(),)).start()
        

    def function(self):
        if threading.active_count() != 1:
            while self.run:
                try:
                    with sr.Microphone(len(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names())-1) as source:
                        self.listener.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
                        print("Listening....")
                        audio = self.listener.listen(source, None, 2)
                        self.command = self.listener.recognize_google(audio).lower()
                        if self.command.lower() == 'ok google' or self.command.lower() == 'hey google' or self.command.lower() == 'google':
                            self.a = True
                        if self.a:
                            if 'bye' in self.command or 'goodbye' in self.command or 'kill yourself' in self.command:
                                a = False
                            if 'tell' in self.command and 'joke' in self.command and "don't" not in self.command and 'do  not' not in self.command:
                
                                self.engine.say(self.command)
                                self.engine.endLoop()
                                #engine.endLoop()
                            if 'play' in self.command or 'youtube' in self.command:
                                self.command = self.command.replace('play', '')
                                self.command = self.command.replace('youtube', '')
                                if self.command.strip() != '':
                                    pywhatkit.playonyt(self.command)
                                else:
                                    pywhatkit.playonyt('never gonna give you up')
                            if 'open' in self.command or 'run' in self.command:
                                self.command = self.command.replace('open', '')
                                self.command = self.command.replace('run', '')
                                if 'whatsapp' in self.command or "chatsappp" in self.command:
                                    if 'in a new group' in self.command:
                                        self.newserver = True
                                    else:
                                        self.newserver = False
                                    self.run1 = True
                                    #threading.Thread(target = (chatApp.run(), )).start
                                    #threading.Condition.wait()

                except Exception as s:
                    print(s)
    def mainScreen(self):        
        
        #self.g.join()
        while self.run:
            #global a,command
            _, frame = self.webcam.read()
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            self.window.blit(self.image, (0, 0))
            self.hand.findHands(frame)
            lmList = self.hand.findPosition(frame)
            fingerup = self.hand.fingersUp()
            self.window.blit(self.googleWidget, (20,0))
            if lmList:
                if fingerup == [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]:
                    x = lmList[8][1]/self.webcam.get(3)
                    y = lmList[8][2]/self.webcam.get(4)
                    self.select = False
                    pyg.draw.circle(self.window, (0, 0, 0), ((self.width+100)*x, (self.height+100)*y), 5)
                elif fingerup == [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]:
                    x = lmList[8][1]/self.webcam.get(3)
                    y = lmList[8][2]/self.webcam.get(4)
                    self.select = True
                    pyg.draw.circle(self.window, (255, 255, 255), ((self.width+100)*x, (self.height+100)*y), 8)
            self.cTime = time.time()
            self.fps = 1 / (self.cTime-self.pTime)
            self.pTime = self.cTime
            
            for event in pyg.event.get():
                if event.type == pyg.QUIT:
                    self.run = False
                    pyg.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            if self.select:
                if self.microphoneRect.collidepoint((self.width+100)*x, (self.height+100)*y):
                    a1 = True
                    a = True
                    self.select = False
            
            self.window.blit(self.chatsappIcon, (100, self.height//2))
            self.a1 = self.a
            if self.run1:
                print("hello")
                chatApp.run()
                    
            
            
            if self.a or self.a1:
                pyg.draw.rect(self.window, (255, 255, 255), (0, self.height/2, self.width, self.height/2), 0, 5)
                google_logo = pyg.image.load('SuryaAssets/Google_Assistant_logo.png')
                google_logo = pyg.transform.scale(google_logo, (100, 100))
                google_logo_rect = google_logo.get_rect()
                google_logo_rect.center = (self.width/2, self.height*3/4)
                self.window.blit(google_logo, google_logo_rect)
                
            buttons = pyg.Surface((self.image.get_width(), 50))
            buttons.set_alpha(100)
            buttons.fill((255, 255, 255))
            self.window.blit(buttons, (0, self.image.get_height()-50))
            pyg.display.update()
            
            #cv2.imshow("window", frame)
            

def main():
    phone = homeScreen()
    #phone.mainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Individually both applications work like charm....but when try opening a thread thread to start server1.function()
it give this error

```
2022-11-21 22:34:30.493 Python[3275:87431] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'nextEventMatchingMask should only be called from the Main Thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204b4beb __exceptionPreprocess + 242
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff201edd92 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   AppKit                              0x00007fff22c40eb6 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 4389
        3   libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib                 0x0000000104de18bd Cocoa_PumpEvents + 125
        4   libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib                 0x0000000104d212c1 SDL_PumpEvents_REAL + 33
        5   event.cpython-310-darwin.so         0x0000000108f56910 pg_event_get + 160
        6   Python                              0x0000000104611244 cfunction_call + 52
        7   Python                              0x00000001045a9fb4 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 132
        8   Python                              0x00000001046ebb53 call_function + 371
        9   Python                              0x00000001046e32f8 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28872
        10  Python                              0x00000001046da8bf _PyEval_Vector + 383
        11  Python                              0x00000001045ae1b1 method_vectorcall + 481
        12  Python                              0x00000001046dcda7 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 2935
        13  Python                              0x00000001046da8bf _PyEval_Vector + 383
        14  Python                              0x00000001046eba8f call_function + 175
        15  Python                              0x00000001046e1d8e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23390
        16  Python                              0x00000001046da8bf _PyEval_Vector + 383
        17  Python                              0x00000001046eba8f call_function + 175
        18  Python                              0x00000001046e1d8e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23390
        19  Python                              0x00000001046da8bf _PyEval_Vector + 383
        20  Python                              0x00000001045ae1b1 method_vectorcall + 481
        21  Python                              0x00000001047e2516 thread_run + 198
        22  Python                              0x00000001047655c4 pythread_wrapper + 36
        23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff203428fc _pthread_start + 224
        24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2033e443 thread_start + 15
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
zsh: abort      /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/surya/Desktop/SuryaFolder/phoneHomeScreen.py
```

So i tried put default threads in hope of just starting server before hand and add a chat app client later on in program but the main thread it self is not running
I know it is in the

```
c, addr = s.accept()
```

But i am not able to make the thread continue without getting a client

Comment: You cannot handle the pygam events within a thread. See [pygame.event.get() not returning any events when inside a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717184/pygame-event-get-not-returning-any-events-when-inside-a-thread)

Comment: Use a single event loop.  From your threads `post` events back to the main loop, processing them there.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11362449/1730895

Answer (score 0):

I don't know every version of Python that's out there, but in the version I'm running (3.9.6), this doesn't do anything useful:

```py
threading.Thread(target=(server1.function(),)).start()
```

That statement is the same as if you did this:

```py
temp_a = server1.function()      # call function()
temp_b = (temp_a,)               # create a new tuple
temp_c = threading.Thread(target=temp_b)
temp_c.start()
```

I don't know what `server1.function()` returns, but the Python 3.9.6 that I'm running does not appear to allow me to use *any* tuple as the `target` of a `Thread`. It lets me *construct* a new `Thread` object, but then it throws an exception when I try to it. Yours isn't throwing the same exception, but it appears to be throwing from within `start()`.